# Store User_choice related to question_id and user_choice

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

Hope you all are well.

I am creating a **mcqs** rails application. I have created the question model in which i have this.

````
```class CreateQuestions < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.1]
  def change
    create_table :questions do |t|
      t.text :question
      t.text :option1
      t.text :option2
      t.text :option3
      t.text :option4
      t.text :answer

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end```
````

Then i create a result model in which i have this.

````
```class CreateResults < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.1]
  def change
    create_table :results do |t|
      t.text :user_choice
      t.integer :q_id
      t.integer :u_id

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end```
````

I make question_id and User_id foreign key in this table.

Now i want to store user_choice compare it with answer and show result to the user that you have enter right or wrong answer.
But now i am unable to make such this. I don't know what to do now.

I will be admire if anybody help me in this regard. I am kinda new to rails. Please help i am stuck here.

````
```class Result < ApplicationRecord

    validates :user_choice, presence: true
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :question

end```
````

This is result model.

This is my question#index view i want to store user_choice from this to result table.

`````
  <div class="card o-hidden border-0 shadow-lg my-5">
    <div class="card-body ">
       <!-- Nested Row within Card Body -->
      <div class="row py-5">
          <div class="p-5">
          <div class="text-center">
       <h1 class="h4 text-gray-900 mb-4 ">Multiple-Choice Questions</h1>
        </div>
    <%= form_with model: @result, url:result_path do |form|%>
   <% @questions.each do |question| %>
    <div id="<%= dom_id(question) %>">
        <p><%= question.question %></p>
        
        <% choices = [question.option1, question.option2, question.option3, question.option4] %>
        <% choices.each do |c| %>
            <div>
                <%= radio_button_tag "guess_#{question.id}", c%>
                <%= label_tag "guess_#{question.id}_#{c}", c  %>
            </div>
        <% end %>
    </div>&nbsp;&nbsp;
<% end %>
       <div class="sub"> <%= button_to "Submit", result_path, class:"btn btn-primary" %></div>
<% end %>
<div class="para1"><%= link_to 'New Question', new_question_path,class:"btn btn-primary btn-user" %>
</div>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
     </div>
  </div>````
`````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your table structure, you can add the following associations

```
class Result < ApplicationRecord
  validates :user_choice, presence: true
  belongs_to :user, foreign_key: :u_id, class_name: 'User'
  belongs_to :question, foreign_key: :q_id, class_name: 'Question'
end
```

And then you can compare the User answer as following

```
def is_answer_correct?
  question.answer == user_choice
end
```

I will also recommend moving the questions option into a separate table. This will make it easy to manage. You can refer to the DB structure added in this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33190665)

View form

```
<div class="card o-hidden border-0 shadow-lg my-5">
    <div class="card-body ">
       <!-- Nested Row within Card Body -->
      <div class="row py-5">
          <div class="p-5">
          <div class="text-center">
       <h1 class="h4 text-gray-900 mb-4 ">Multiple-Choice Questions</h1>
        </div>
    <%= form_with model: @result do |form|%>
   <% @questions.each do |question| %>
    <div id="<%= dom_id(question) %>">
        <%= f.hidden_field, :question_id, question.id %>
        <p><%= question.question %></p>
        
        <% choices = [question.option1, question.option2, question.option3, question.option4] %>
        <% choices.each do |c| %>
            <div>
                <%= form.radio_button :user_choice, c %>
                <%= form.label :user_choice, c  %>
            </div>
        <% end %>
    </div>&nbsp;&nbsp;
<% end %>
       <div class="sub"> <%= form.submit "Submit", class:"btn btn-primary" %></div>
<% end %>
<div class="para1"><%= link_to 'New Question', new_question_path,class:"btn btn-primary btn-user" %>
</div>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
     </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Ok thanks but can you help me here that when i save user_choice i also have to store u_id and q_id so who can i do that?? In my mind the only answer is joins but how can i add joins in rails i mean where to write the query in result model?? or how to write because from net i haven't yet get any idea please help me in this

Comment: In your ResultsController create action, you can save the q_id and u_id. `Result.create(user_choice: params[:user_choice], q_id: params[:question_id], u_id: current_user.id)`

Comment: I did the same but when i press submit it doesn't change the path mean it didn't redirect to other page and even not save a single thing in pgadmin

Comment: Can you share the view code?

Comment: I have update the question please check.

Comment: Seems like your radio button and submit button are not associated with form. You will have to use `form.radio_button :user_choice, c` and `form.submit`. Also check in your controller if all the params are present.

Comment: I have updated the answer with latest view code, try that and see if it works

Comment: no implicit conversion of Integer into Hash it's showing this error

Comment: @AbuBakar At which line??

Comment: the f.hidden_field line where we have question_id

Comment: I removed question.id from there then i show me the page but the values doesn't save

Comment: it's working brother thank you sop much the issue was we havn't erote value before question.id

Comment: The syntax will be like value: question.id

Comment: Now just need one more favor from you how can we group the radio buttons?

Comment: I have all the questions on one page and when i select the option it's select for one option at a time mean for one question only when i check the second question the first question unchecked i don't know why

Comment: Glad you found it helpful!

Comment: I'm not sure, you might have to use nested_attributes. Check this SO post if this helps you https://stackoverflow.com/a/37912830

Comment: Yes thanks.
 Can you please help me about this what is happening here?

Comment: When you will submit your forn, there will multiple result records created (one for each question). So using nested attributes it will submit the params in array of hashes format.

Comment: Feel free to create a new SO question for this, you might get some more better way to handle this.

Comment: Ok let me check

Comment: Yes it's working now that to you not only one issue remains that the question id is not changing i don't know

Comment: Hi bro actually the question_id is not changing for any of the choice and i want different ids 
<% @questions.each do |question| %>
  <%= f.fields_for question do |fq| %>
    <%= fq.hidden_field :question_id, value: question.id  %>
    ...
  <% end %>
<% end %>
 Here what i try to use but it's not saving the choice with this field can you help me in this please

Comment: Sure @AbuBakar, Can you try to print the question id on UI and see what the value is? Just add this above hidden field line `<%= question.id %>`.

Comment: Also the issue is when you submit the form, the question id is not changing? right?

Comment: Yes the issue is that question.id is not changing

Comment: Hi the <%= question.id %> shows the right id of the question but i want to store question id of all the selected question on submit button so i can use it to compare answers

Comment: Please tell me what to do now

Comment: Can you share the params sent to the controller, when you submit the form

Comment: def create
            @result=Result.create(user_choice: params[:user_choice], 
            question_id: params[:question_id], 
            user_id: current_user.id)
    end

Comment: These are the params for resut controller

Comment: No, When you submit the form. Check the logs and see what fields are getting submitted

Comment: User_choice, user_id and question_id these fields. Data is coming in these field the issue is i think because of each loop the loop starts from one and where it ends it store and show the last one not confirm just saying